# Lubuntu 13.04 minimal auto-login deosn't work

Tags: lubuntu, auto-login, lxdm

I have install lubuntu 13.04 minimal on an old netbook.
I would like to use autologin.

I have changed the first lines of `/etc/lxdm/default.conf` to the following:

```
autologin=arthur
timeout=3
session=/usr/bin/startlubuntu-netbook
```

But it doesn't change anything. Everytime I start the netbook I have to choose my user and enter the password.

Thanks!

Regards,
Arthur

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo su
nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf or nano /etc/lxdm/lightdm.conf
```

Make sure that the following two lines are in there, save the file and exit, reboot to test.

```
autologin-user=USERNAME
autologin-user-timeout=0
```